# Unity TCP client constructor error in Universal Windows Platform build

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, build

I tried to build my Unity project on Universal Windows Platform for PC and I get the following error:
[image: Build error]
The error is: "Value does not fall within the expected range", in the line: "`TcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);`".
The ip is set to "127.0.0.1" and the port to 6666, but even if I run the TcpClient construction method that takes no ip and port, I still get the same error. 
The projects works even with this error, except that the TCP client isn't connecting to the server. 

I am working on Unity 2019.3.5f1, and this error occurs only when I am running the Universal Windows Platform build.
In the editor or in other types of builds it works fine.

**EDIT:**
After some more research I found that the error is in the `SetSocketOption` method, that is called by the TcpClient constructing method.

Comment: could you debug which ip and port are you using on that platform?

Comment: So is your problem solved, or do you just know where the problem is located?

Comment: I didn't managed to solved it, but with some modifications I successfully build the project for another platform.